# call approval process to lock the record some time after the record is created

Tags: approval-process, configuration

I  have a requirement that whenever I create a Job object record (*Job is my custom object here) an approval process should be called to lock the record but after three days of the creation of record.

I tried to achieve this with the help of process builder but in this case when the job is created all the criteria are not satisfied hence the approval process is not triggered.

Please guide me how to call an approval process after three days of the creation of record

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach:

> Approach 1

1. Create a checkbox field let's say `isFireApproval`.
2. Define a time based workflow which will fire after 72 hours based on creation date. In that action, update `isFireApproval=true` through workflow field update.
3. In the workflow field update configuration section select the checkbox `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change`. (**otherwise, process builder's process will not fire**)
4. Create an approval process on that Job object which will also check `isFireApproval=true`.
5. Define a process builder's process (when a record is created or edited) with a criteria `isFireApproval=true` which will submit for approval.

**Process flow:**

[image: process flow]

Through approval process you can lock the record.

> **Update based on comments**

To support the Approach 1, I have created this process and it will be perfectly working.

> 1. Workflow field update configuration

[image: Workflow field]

> 2. Workflow rule configuration

[image: Workflow rule configuration]

> 3. Approval process configuration

[image: Approval process configuration]

> 4. Process builder configuration

[image: Process builder configuration]

> 5. Final output

[image: screen]

Otherwise,

> Approach 2

1. Create a checkbox field let's say `isFireApproval`.
2. Define a time based workflow which will fire after 72 hours based on creation date. In that action, update `isFireApproval=true` through workflow field update.
3. In the workflow field update section select the checkbox `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change`.
4. Create a create trigger (after update) and lock the record using `Approval.lock()`

   Refer [Approval Class - lock method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm)

   `Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(List<SObject> recordsToLock);`

You can also refer my blog post in case it helps:

[Locking Salesforce records for concurrent users to view or to perform any other actions](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/locking-salesforce-records-for.html) .

Comment: Hello Santanu , I executed everything as you said but in the last step I m getting an error .The process builder is not able to call the approval process hence the flow isn't completed so when I create any record it is showing the following error   :

Comment: "Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow
The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301280000007zzm. Flow error messages: &lt;b&gt;An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information. Contact your administrator for help. 

Click here to return to the previous page."

Comment: This is working perfectly while I am using a trigger but it would have been better if I achieved the same result using process builder

Comment: The way I have described, Approach 1 is perfectly working, See the updated answer with the screenshot. Configuration works perfectly.

Comment: yes the functionality is wirking perfectly using both the approaches.Thank you for the answers